# Task scheduling in Zookeeper

Tags: configuration, apache-zookeeper

I am trying Zookeeper for storing the configs for services, so one functionality I need is scheduling, i.e. for some mentioned duration I will swap my current config, with some other config. How can I achieve this in Zookeeper?

Also what is the best UI for the zookeeper?

Answer (score 1):

> **Q:** I am trying Zookeeper for storing the configs for services, so one
>   functionality I need is scheduling, i.e. for some mentioned duration I
>   will swap my current config, with some other config. How can I achieve
>   this in Zookeeper?

Let's assume that you have two applications, one that sets configuration (let's call it `A`) and the other that reads it (let's call it `B`). `A` should create znode in ZooKeeper, named for example `/config`, with the configuration data inside. Note that a single znode can keep up to 1 MB of data - that should be probably enough for keeping the configuration. `B` then needs to read the content of znode `/config` and register a [watch](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.1-alpha/zookeeperProgrammers.html#ch_zkWatches). The purpose of watch is to notify `B` whenever something changes with that znode.

Particularly, when `A` writes new configuration into `/config`, watch will ensure that `B` gets a notification about it. Important note - watch event is **one-time** trigger, i.e. when `B` gets notification, it needs to register a watch again or it will miss further changes. Also note that ZooKeeper itself does not have any built-in scheduler mechanism - `A` will have to rely on its system clock to update the configuration within the specified time frame.

> **Q:** Also what is the best UI for the zookeeper?

Haven't personally tried any of these ([zkCli](https://github.com/go-zkcli/zkcli) fits my needs), but supposedly the most popular are:

- [ZooNavigator](https://github.com/elkozmon/zoonavigator)
- [zkui](https://github.com/DeemOpen/zkui)
- [zooinspector](https://github.com/zzhang5/zooinspector)

Comment: Can you give an example of re-registering the watch?

Comment: @JSR29 Yes, if you are using C API you can write: `void create_session() { zookeeper_init(host, connection_watcher, TIMEOUT, nullptr, this, 0); }` and the implementation of `connection_watcher` would be: `void connection_watcher(zhandle_t*  zh, int  type, int state, const char* path, void* v) {
 if (state == ZOO_EXPIRED_SESSION_STATE)
  create_session();
}`

Comment: @JSR29 Notice that in case of trigger, `create_session` gets invoked again and watch `connection_watcher` gets re-registered through the `zookeeper_init` call. In your case, you should provide watcher to `zoo_wget` function.

Comment: I am using JAVA API.

Comment: @JSR29 The logic is same. In watcher body (in my example, `connection_watcher`) just invoke again the method that registered the watcher (in my example, `create_session`).

Comment: @JSR29 Is there anything I can add to complete my answer? Was it helpful?